# How to limit my node.js client connections to 2?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am basically trying to only allow 2 clients to connect to the app concurrently. How should I approach this?

This is my server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var osc = require('node-osc');

var client = new osc.Client('127.0.0.1', 12345);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        client.send('/oscAddress', parseInt(data));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try with

```
server.maxConnections = 2;
```

Never used it but is looks like it's the way to go if I trust the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#net_server_maxconnections)

Comment: I tried this.. but for some reason the mouse position data i'm sending is now very slow.. or working every now and then, even though I only have 2 clients open

Comment: If you send data each time your mouse moves, you are not one client, each sending is considered as a client by the server. That's why it's queuing the data. Why do you want to limit to 2 clients in the first place ?

Comment: I'm trying to set up my phone as a controller for an arduino. The way it goes is: browser-server-open-frameworks(via osc)-arduino etc. I only need 2 controllers at the same time. Not more. I want to replace them when the other users disconnects.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it fixed the problem I asked about.. However.. i did not ask the correct question. My problem persists.. data seems to be queueing and timing out and stuff

Comment: You maybe should think of a solution based on a token, cookie or pool of connections to control that.

Comment: Hmm.. This gets way to complicated for what I need.. I actually have a workaround. Instead of limiting the number of client connections(which was preferable) I can limit the number of osc channels. Thank you anyway for your help. :)

Comment: And what if you're just using app.listen() ?