# Node JS how to limit maximum number of sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, connection

is it possibile to set the maximum number of sockets that my server can handle? Something like: maxSocket = 2 and from the 3 attempt of a socket to connect automatically refuse that connection?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have a counter in my server app, and  whenever a client connects succesfully, check that counter and if needed manually call socket.disconnect(). I wonder if there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: think this is what you are referring to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088253/how-to-limit-my-node-js-client-connections-to-2

Answer (score 1):

The default maxSockets value is `Infinity` and it determines the limit of number of sockets per host. See official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets

You can manually set maxSockets limit using the following code snippet

```
require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 10
```

`globalAgent`: Global instance of Agent which is used as the default for all HTTP client requests.

Answer (score 0):

> In Node.js, you can set the maximum number of connections per origin.
>   If maxSockets is set, the low-level HTTP client queues requests and
>   assigns them to sockets as they become available.

[Ref URL from AWS JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html)

According to [Node.js Doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets),

> By default set to Infinity. Determines how many concurrent sockets the
>   agent can have open per origin. Origin is either a 'host:port' or
>   'host:port:localAddress' combination.

Conventionally, they recommend 25~50, I guess.